# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '200' (T_LNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';' in php

Tags: php, html

i keep on getting this error each time i try to set the image height and width. i tried everything to fix this, including fixing the image height and width using css but still it doesn't work. any suggestions?

this is my code:

```
 <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","wallpapers"); 
    $result=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM `desktop_wallpapers`");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<img src=".$row['image']." height="200">";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line (concatenation error).

```
echo "<img src=".$row['image']." height="200">";
```

with this

```
echo '<img src="'.$row['image'].'" height="200">';
```

you should used single quote `'` outside of html and double quote `"` inside on html tag attributes